Ionic component styles not loading with Angular SSR
I'm using Angular 18 standalone application with Ionic 8 and enabled server side rendering. When I try to run SSR, the styles of ionic components are not loading. It just loads the plain html.

server.ts:
        commonEngine
        .render({
            bootstrap,
            documentFilePath: indexHtml,
            url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
            publicPath: distFolder,
            inlineCriticalCss: false,
            providers: [
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
                { provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: req },
                { provide: 'RESPONSE', useValue: res }
            ]
        })
        .then((html) => {
            // Inietta dinamicamente il CSS nel contenuto HTML generato
            if (cssFileName) {
                html = html.replace(
                    '</head>',
                    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssFileName}"></head>`
                );
            }
            res.send(html);
        })
        .catch((err) => next(err));
});


SSR does not work yet with ionic web components. The Angular team needs to fix this.
